# Connect to local MySQL database in JBoss EWS 2.0

Tags: mysql, jboss, openshift

I created an OpenShift application (Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)) and with the help of  [developercorey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2879327/developercorey) I was able to deploy my application to OpenShift and connect to the the local MySQL database in OpenShift.

I am now trying to connect to the same database only on my local machine but when I call initialContext.lookup("jdbc/local") it throws an error.  It's acting like its unable to find the context.xml file even though when the application is deployed in OpenShift it works correctly.

Exception: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initialNeed to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionnull

I am used to Tomcat and the location for datasources is located in: 
WebContent\META-INF\context.xml

But for JBoss the context.xml is located in:
.openshift\config\context.xml

Is there additional mapping I need to do to make the application connect locally?

Thanks in advance!

```
    private static DataSource getDataSource() {
     DataSource datasource = null;
    try {
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        Context initialContext = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
        datasource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("jdbc/local");          
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + ex + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        return datasource;
    }
}


<Resource name="jdbc/OpenShift"
          url="jdbc:mysql://127.10.198.2:3306/remote"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          username="root"
          password="*****"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="5"
          maxWait="10000"
          />

<Resource name="jdbc/local"
          url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/local"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          username="root"
          password="******"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="20"
          maxIdle="5"
          maxWait="10000"
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. When working on OpenShift, the path you need to update the context.xml file is indeed .openshift\config\context.xml

However, if you're working locally. You need to update the context.xml under the following path - $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but where is the $CATALINA_BASE located?  I have JBoss installed in the following directory: C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap

Comment: That did the trick, for JBOSS-EAP 6 the context.xml is located within C:\jbdevstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml There is where I was able to add the datasource element